# Rails 3.2.x: How to change logging levels without restarting the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I would like to change the logging levels of a running Rails 3.2.x application without restarting the application. My intent is to use it to do short-time debugging and information gathering before reverting it to the usual logging level.

I also understand that the levels in ascending order are debug, info, warn, error, and fatal, and that production servers log info and higher, while development logs debug and higher.

I understand that if I run

```
Rails.logger.level=:debug #or :info, :warn, :error, :fatal
```

Will this change the logging level immediately?

If so, can I do this by writing a Rake task to adjust the logging level, or do I need to support this by adding a route? For example in config/routes.rb:

```
match "/set_logging_level/:level/:secret" => "logcontroller#setlevel"
```

and then setting the levels in the logcontroller. (:level is the logging level, and :secret which is shared between client and server, is something to prevent random users from tweaking the log levels)

Which is more appropriate, rake task or /set_logging_level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have to change the level in the *running* rails instance, a simple rake task will not work.
I would go with the dedicated route.

instead of a *shared secret* I would use the app's standard user authentication (if your app has users) and restrict access to admin/super user.

Comment: I did it in the running instance, and it worked. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 15):

Why don't you use operating system signals for that? For example on UNIX user1 and user2 signals are free to use for your application:

```
config/initializers/signals.rb:

trap('USR1') do
  Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
end

trap('USR2') do
  Rails.logger.level = Logger::WARN
end
```

Then just do this:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 pid
kill -SIGUSR2 pid
```

Just make sure you dont override signals of your server - each server leverages various signals for things like log rotation, child process killing and terminating and so on.

Comment: Good idea. Except some servers (E.g. unicorn, for one) already use these signals.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails console, you can simply do:

```
Rails.logger.level = :debug
```

Now all executed code will run with this log level

Answer (score 4):

In your controller LogController try this

```
def setlevel
  begin
      Rails.logger.level = Logger.const_get(params[:level].upcase)
  rescue
      logger.info("Logging level #{params[:level]} not supported")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use gdb to attach to the running process, set the Rails.logger to debug level and then detach. I have created the following 1 liner to do this for my puma process:

```
gdb attach $(pidof puma) -ex 'call(rb_eval_string("Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG"))' -ex detach -ex quit
```

*NOTE: pidof will return multiple pids, in descending order. So if you have multiple processes with the same name this will only run on the first one returned by pidof. The others will be discarded by the "gdb attach" command with the message: "Excess command line arguments ignored. (26762)". However you can safely ignore it if you only care about the first process returned by pidof.*

Answer (score 1):

Using rufus-scheduler, I created this schedule:

```
scheduler.every 1.second do
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/change_log_level.#{Process.pid}"
  if File.exists? file_path
    log_level = File.open(file_path).read.strip
    case log_level
    when "INFO"
      Rails.logger.level = Logger::INFO
      Rails.logger.info "Changed log_level to INFO"
    when "DEBUG"
      Rails.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
      Rails.logger.info "Changed log_level to DEBUG"
    end
    File.delete file_path
  end
end
```

Then, log level can be changed by creating a file under `tmp/change_log_level.PID`, where `pid` is the process id of the rails process. You can create a rake/capistrano task to detect and create these files, allowing you to quickly switch log level of your running production server.

Just remember to start rufus in the worker threads, if you are using unicorn or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think of this as a great example of something to put on top of a dynamic configuration system. Dynamic configuration takes care of propagating out the log level to the servers in realtime, then when logging occurs it can evaluate the current state of the log level. Most FeatureFlags products work in a similar way pushing new config like this.

The advantage of this is that beyond a simple global log level, you can have a more complex LogLevel object with rules. This let's you turn on `DEBUG` for `user1234` for the `Services::Billing` class `90 minutes`.

I've built [prefab.cloud](https://prefab.cloud) with this in mind so that would be worth checking out. The core ruby code for dynamic logging is in https://github.com/prefab-cloud/prefab-cloud-ruby/blob/main/lib/prefab/logger_client.rb

Simplified, this is:

```rb
    def log(message, path, progname, severity)
      severity ||= ::Logger::UNKNOWN

      return true if severity < level_of(@dynamic_config.get(path, @context))
      ...log as normal...
    end
```

If you didn't want to use Prefab, you could use another dynamic configuration system to do something similar.